# xpath select node texts and child nodes

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using python scrapy to scrape some data from a website.

the web site content is something like this

```
 <html>
  <div class="details">
  <div class="a"> not needed</div>
  content 1
  <p>content 2</p>
  <div>content 2</div>
  <p>content 2</p>
  <div>content 2</div>
  <p>content 2</p>
  <div class="b"> this is also not needed</div>
  </div>
 </html>
```

I need to get the full html data excluding div with class a,b.

so my output will be like this

```
<div class="details">   
content 1
<p>content 2</p>
<div>content 2</div>
<p>content 2</p>
<div>content 2</div>
<p>content 2</p>
</div>
```

How can I write correct xpath for that or should I write xpath for div with class 'details','a','b 'and use string operations to remove div with class 'a','b'?

Note that here content   is the text of and is not a child of div with class 'details'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all children except the `div` with class `a` or `b` using `node()` and `self::` syntax:

```
//div[@class="details"]/node()[not(self::div[@class="a" or @class="b"])]
```

Demo using [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> nodes = response.xpath('//div[@class="details"]/node()[not(self::div[@class="a" or @class="b"])]').extract()
>>> print ''.join(nodes)
  content 1
  <p>content 2</p>
  <div>content 2</div>
  <p>content 2</p>
  <div>content 2</div>
  <p>content 2</p>
```